# Significant performance difference within integers of different bits for small numbers

Tags: c#, performance, variables, integer

I am going to be using very small numbers in really large quantities (As in each int will be between 1 and 10 and have 100s of variables like this at a time) for the first time, and I was wondering if there was any significant performance differences in using 16 bit integers VS 32 bit. Most of my users will be using 64 bit processors but some will have 32 bit.

Comment: Sounds like a case of premature optimization.  What makes you think these variables will be the largest source of performance problems in your application?  For instance, sending a network request to a database can take 100s of times longer than allocating a 1000-element array.

Comment: What will you be doing with those numbers?

Comment: In general terms, integers that match the processor's native integer size (32-bit on 32-bit CPU, 64-bit on 64-bit CPU) will perform the fastest.  However, this is no excuse not to test and benchmark -- there may be factors other than just how quickly the CPU can manipulate integers, such as swapping, cache misses, etc.

Comment: 100s of variables is not a large amount for any modern computer. Before reaching hundreds of thousands or millions of numbers you will probably not see any significant difference.

Comment: mellamokb, it most definately won't be but I want to cut down even the smallest bit. Thomas Levesque, they will change very rarely (maybe a few of them changing every 20 seconds or so) but will be accessed constantly. cdhowie, I'm aware of this but I was wondering if since the numbers will be so small if there was anything else to consider. Anders Abel, good point but they will be used (as in "if" statements and such) very rapidly, if that changes anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**CPU**

When working with individual numbers, there will *possibly* be a slight improvement using a more compact representation.  That is,

```
ushort a;
ushort b;

// @mikez pointed a & b are  promoted to int when added
// C# spec, 7.3.6.2 Binary numeric promotions
ushort result = (ushort)(a + b);
```

*might* be slightly faster than

```
ulong a;
ulong b;

ulong result = a + b;
```

*depending on* your algorithms.  The reason is that more data can fit in CPU cache when the individual numbers are smaller, and ultimately less data has to be transferred from RAM to the CPU.

On the other hand, it might be *slightly slower* due to reading/writing data that is not aligned to a 64-bit address boundary.

Both factors work against each other.  Measure your use cases to find out if you're better or worse off from a CPU perspective.

**In RAM**

Using a `List<ushort>` instead of a `List<ulong>` will save 75% in terms of memory cost.  *If* this prevents swapping, it will benefit your application.

**On Disk**

If you are saving to a database, and if your working set is too large to fit in RAM available to the database engine, using the smaller size can have a huge difference on performance because more records fit onto fewer sectors of your disk reducing disk seek time (assuming no SSD) and increasing the amount of data points that can be transferred through the IO channel per unit time.

**Caveat**

Note that all of this *only* matters if **really large quantities** is true in comparison to the processing power of your computer.  If you have enough RAM to keep all data in memory, you will not swap.  If your database server and/or storage controller cache can keep your working set in memory, disk storage size considerations will matter little.

**Bottom Line**

Using a smaller data type will only hurt you if you were wrong about the range of values you will process, and you suddenly need a larger data type to hold all values.

Do a quick prototype of your key algorithms.  Perform some measurements using various choices of ushort, uint, ulong.

If your "100's of variables" each only contain a single number (as opposed to, say, a list with lots and lots of numbers), none of this matters.  Only when you start to put pressure on your computer (maybe in 10's to 100's of millions of data points or more, depending on what you are doing) will these optimizations matter in a real way to your users.

Comment: +1. Nice summary. Consider adding "measure first" to be ideal :). I would put CPU in more "may improve or potentially degrade performance due to non-aligned read/writes".

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, but one more question, if using smaller values DOES add to performance in a particular case, then will converting the integers to bigger integers for temporary use balance it out or even hurt performance?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yeah I added that in.  Was working on the answer a bit at a time.

Comment: @leaf68: That depends.  If you have say 1 billion values you're dealing with in general and need to convert 1,000 of them to a larger type to do some processing, *probably* you're net positive keeping things small until needed.  If the numbers are different, I suggest you run some simulations and measure your use cases.

Comment: Actually the first example won't even compile because + is not defined for `ushort`. Modern processors are heavily optimized for 32- and 64-bit operations and don't actually have built in operations for smaller representations (16- or 8-bit). I'm guessing the framework is trying to tell us "don't do math with these because it isn't efficient" by not defining the arithmetic operators.

Comment: @mikez: Good point, I hadn't considered that.  Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If in doubt, measure. But apart from the memory consumption difference I doubt you will see anything.

Answer (score 2):

The answers here are good in general, however there is a specific consideration on the .NET platform: There are no 8- or 16-bit arithmetic operations in CIL.

That means that all 8- and 16-bit values are implicitly converted to 32-bit for the purpose of arithmetic.

[ECMA Specs - Part 3 (CIL)](http://jilc.sourceforge.net/ecma_p3_cil.shtml) - Section 1.6 Implicit Argument Coercion

Comment: hmm... is there a way to get around this so that it operates on 16 bit numbers natively?

Comment: Interop overhead to do individual operations would be horrible from a performance perspective.  I would also *measure* the impact of this before doing anything about it.  I don't suspect that this will contribute much to total performance cost of the app.

Comment: @EricJ. Right, if you were going to interop you would want to do it in large "chucks" (i.e. perform the entire operation natively).